# iOS deadlocks when calling dispatch_sync from main queue and the executed block saves to Core data

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, deadlock

I have an implementation of Core Data that uses parent contexts.
I have a main context that runs on main queue and a back context that runs on a private queue and the main context is his parent.

I override the context save method with the following:

```
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error {
  BOOL retVal = YES;

  if (self.parentContext) {
    //push changes to parent context.
    retVal = [super save:error];

    if (retVal) {
      //save parent context.
      [self.parentContext performBlock:^{
        [self.parentContext save:error];
      }];
    }
  } else {
    //save changes.
    retVal = [super save:error];
  }

  return retVal;
}
```

My problem is when my main queue calls:

```
- (BOOL)doSomething {
  __block BOOL retVal;

  dispatch_sync(workerQueue, ^{
    retVal = [super doSomething];
  });

  return retVal;
}
```

if `[super doSomething]` has a call to the context save method I get a deadlock (the dead lock is in the line: `retVal = [super save:error];`  in my save method).

Here is the stack trace for the worker queue:

```
0 semaphore_wait_trap
1_dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$mp
2_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow
3_perform 
4-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error]
5 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:]
```

Here is the stack trace for the main queue:

```
0 semaphore_wait_trap 
1 _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$mp 
2 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow 
3 [Service doSomething]
```

**for some strange reason this happens only on iPad and not iPhone**

Is there a way to overcome this deadlock using recursive locks?

Comment: "for some strange reason this happens only on iPad and not iPhone" <-- this may be a good indication of a race condition existing somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You must not use your own dispatch queues for Core Data operations. Use `performBlock:` 
or `performBlockAndWait:` to ensure that the operation is executed on the queue
associated with the managed object context.

See "Concurrency" in the [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext).